# Get text part of clicked URL in TTTAttributedLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, tttattributedlabel

I need the text of clicked part of `TTTAttributedLabel`:

```
// initialize
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...

    // Attributed Message Label
    NSMutableAttributedString *messageTextAttr =[row valueForKey:@"message_text_attr"];

    cell.messageText.attributedText = messageTextAttr;
    cell.messageText.delegate = self;

    [messageTextAttr enumerateAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, messageTextAttr.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
        if (value) {
            [cell.messageText addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:value] withRange:range];
        }
    }];

    ...
}

// click event
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"link %@", [url absoluteString]);
    NSLog(@"whole label %@", label);
}
```

But I have only the link and whole label, but not the clicked part (text part which is clicked). How can I get it?

Comment: the URL is the link you pressed, are you adding custom linkAttributes for stuff like @ , # ?

Comment: @SeanLintern88 No, I need text part of label which is clicked, not whole text of it.

Comment: Yes the URL is the text the person clicked. url.absoluteString()?

Comment: Each link has two part: URL and text, I need the text

Comment: Can you add the code of how you are initializing the TTTAttributedLabel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is implementing `attributedLabel: didSelectLinkWithTextCheckingResult:` instead of `attributedLabel: didSelectLinkWithURL:`.

It's benefit is that the `NSTextCheckingResult` contains a **range** property that you can use to find the actual text (not the URL) clicked.

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithTextCheckingResult:(NSTextCheckingResult *)result {

    NSString* textClicked = [label.text substringWithRange:result.range];

    //Get the URL and perform further actions
    NSURL* urlClicked = result.URL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** snippet

```
func attributedLabel(_ label: TTTAttributedLabel!, didSelectLinkWith result: NSTextCheckingResult!) {
    guard let checkingResult = result else { return }
    guard let clickedURL = checkingResult.url else { return }
    guard let text = label.text as? NSString else { return }

    let clickedText = text.substring(with: checkingResult.range)
}
```